# Batch FOR, CALL: Why can't I pass a token to my subroutine?

Tags: windows, batch-processing

This must be quite simple.  Unfortunately, so am I.

"filelist.txt" is the output of: dir /b

This code works: for every line in 'filelist.txt', that line is echoed as expected.

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (filelist.txt) do echo %%A
```

This code doesn't work: for every line in 'filelist.txt', only the var name "%A" is echoed.

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (filelist.txt) do call :sub1
goto :eof
:sub1
echo %%A
goto :eof
```

What am I doing wrong?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (filelist.txt) do call :sub1 %%A
goto :eof
:sub1
echo %1
goto :eof
```

You need to pass your argument (`%%A`) to the subroutine ([arg guide](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)) and then inside your subroutine you can access it by position (`%1`).

Comment: Thanks Rudu!  That was it.  Rock on!